# How to know if method is taking array as param using reflection

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, methods

I am trying to invoke the API with the given input parameters. Input params are coming as a List. Now my job is get the API's parameter types one by one and build the required type instance from List. I am able to do for simple java types , List, Set but I am stuck at the array.

```
Method  method = getMethodFromTheClassBasedOnvalues(  loadedClass,   apiName, numberOfParams);
     Type[] apiMethodParams = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
         List<Type> expectedParamTypes = Arrays.asList(apiMethodArgTypes);
     List<Object> actualValues = // method input.

    List<Object> argsList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < expectedParamTypes.length; i++) {
        argsList.add(castToRequiredType(expectedParamTypes.get(i),
                actualValues.get(i)));

    method.invoke(loadClass.newInstance(), argsList.toArray());
```

The problem comes when I get the method which is of type API (String, String[]) I try to get GenericTypes by calling method.getGenericParameterTypes() which returns and array something like this :
 `[class java.lang.String, class [Ljava.lang.String;]`  or if one parameter [Ljava.lang.String;
Based on this how would I know if its taking Array of String. I see difference is class name is starting after [L and finishes with; but is it guaranteed?
Will the bevhiour be same for CustomObject[] also?

Is there any smart way to know if the method is taking an array and to build it lately?
Any thoughts in this direction will help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

> Class[] Mehotd.getParameterTypes()

After that you can call Class.isArray() and determine does this parameter class is array

Answer (score 2):

[L means an array of objects indeed. See for example [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29).
But the best way to check if some class represents an array, is the [isArray](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray%28%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown what `castToRequiredType` is doing, but if you ever end up casting the `Type` to `Class`, you'll be able to use `Class.isArray` and `Class.getComponentType`.

Comment: Type string to cast the input value to the required type. It can be something like this.       `Object returnValue = null;
        String type = typeString;
        if (typeString.contains(CLASS_STRING)) {
            typeString = typeString.replaceFirst(CLASS_STRING, "");
        }
        if (isTypePrimitive(type)) {
            returnValue = castToPrimitive(object.toString(), typeString);
        } else if (type.startsWith("java.util.List")) {
            returnValue = getListTypeParam(typeString, object); `

Comment: @java_enthu: That's not terribly clear, as a Type isn't a String. But I would strongly advise *against* using the string representation directly.

Comment: @java_enthu: You *still* haven't shown where `typeString` is coming from though.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. typeString is to be found from the API parameter types. As mentioned in the original post. For each parameter of the API I need to build the required type object from a list of actualValues.expectedParamTypes will contain the list of parameter types which i am getting from the API's getGenericParamTypes.

Comment: @java_enthu: `typeString` isn't mentioned anywhere before these comments. I askedabout what was happening in `castToRequiredType` which appears to be where you're using `expectedParamTypes`. As I said before, using the string representation is a *really bad idea* given that you've got a far richer API with `Class` etc.

Comment: @Jon, I think you are right perhapes I should have used Class istead of String. I will check if I can refector it. Thank you.